# how to do ajax call from hudson/jenkins jelly?

Tags: ajax, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I was given the responsibility of working on a Hudson/Jenkins plugin that someone else wrote, and i'm new to this...

In one of the config.jelly files, there is javascript code that starts this way:

```
new Ajax.Request("../../descriptorByName/com.mycompany.jenkins.ScriptExecutionBuilder/getParameters", {
```

i know it's attempting to call the getParameters method of the specified java class by using ajax, but i would really appreciate if i could get answers to some of these questions:
1) what is the relative current location from which the url starts climbing up using the "../"
2) what is the meaning of "../../descriptorByName"? it seems like the "descriptorByName" is a keyword and does not refer to some folder location...
3) where can i find the description of the "new Ajax.Request" and its parameters and what it means to be invoked from the context of a Jenkins .jelly?
4) The problem i'm trying to solve: when this ajax call is triggered from a job in the "All" view it works fine (reaches the method in the java class), however, if i create a new Jenkins view with this job in it, and when i trigger the above ajax call from within the view, the ajax call fails - the java method never gets executed. i get the response shown below. how can i specify the ajax request url "../../descr..." in such a way that it would work when triggered from any view (not just the "All" view?)

---

The response i'm getting when triggering the above ajax while configuring the job in a view named "SpecialView" is this:

```
<a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('valerr26').style.display='block';return false">ERROR</a><div id="valerr26" style="display:none"><html><body>
<h1>404 Not Found</h1>
<p>Stapler processed this HTTP request as follows, but couldn't find the resource to consume the request
<pre>
-> evaluate(&lt;hudson.model.Hudson@5ac3cc2d> :hudson.model.Hudson,"/view/SpecialView/descriptorByName/com.mycompany.jenkins.ScriptExecutionBuilder/getParameters")
-> evaluate(((StaplerProxy)&lt;hudson.model.Hudson@5ac3cc2d>).getTarget(),"/view/SpecialView/descriptorByName/com.mycompany.jenkins.ScriptExecutionBuilder/getParameters")
-> evaluate(&lt;hudson.model.Hudson@5ac3cc2d>.getView("SpecialView"),"/descriptorByName/com.mycompany.jenkins.ScriptExecutionBuilder/getParameters")
-> evaluate(&lt;hudson.model.ListView@746cd6da> :hudson.model.ListView,"/descriptorByName/com.mycompany.jenkins.ScriptExecutionBuilder/getParameters")
-> evaluate(&lt;hudson.model.ListView@746cd6da>.getDynamic("descriptorByName",...),"/com.mycompany.jenkins.ScriptExecutionBuilder/getParameters")
            hudson.model.ListView@746cd6da.getDynamic("descriptorByName",...)==null. Back tracking.
<font color=red>-&gt; No matching rule was found on &lt;hudson.model.ListView@746cd6da&gt; for "/descriptorByName/com.mycompany.jenkins.ScriptExecutionBuilder/getParameters"</font>
</pre>
<p>&lt;hudson.model.ListView@746cd6da&gt; has the following URL mappings, in the order of preference:<ol>
<li>
hudson.model.ListView.doAddJobToView(...) for url=/addJobToView/...
<li>
hudson.model.ListView.doRemoveJobFromView(...) for url=/removeJobFromView/...
<li>
hudson.model.ListView.doCreateItem(...) for url=/createItem/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.doRssAll(...) for url=/rssAll/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.doRssFailed(...) for url=/rssFailed/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.doDoDelete(...) for url=/doDelete/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.doConfigDotXml(...) for url=/config.xml/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.doConfigSubmit(...) for url=/configSubmit/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.doSubmitDescription(...) for url=/submitDescription/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.doRssLatest(...) for url=/rssLatest/...
<li>
TOKEN.groovy for url=/TOKEN
<li>
VIEW.jelly for url=/VIEW
<li>
hudson.model.Saveable.NOOP for url=/NOOP/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.LIST for url=/LIST/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.SORTER for url=/SORTER/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.PERMISSIONS for url=/PERMISSIONS/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.CREATE for url=/CREATE/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.DELETE for url=/DELETE/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.CONFIGURE for url=/CONFIGURE/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.READ for url=/READ/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.NEW_PRONOUN for url=/NEW_PRONOUN/...
<li>
hudson.model.Saveable.NOOP for url=/NOOP/...
<li>
hudson.model.ListView.getJobFilters() for url=/jobFilters/...
<li>
hudson.model.ListView.getIncludeRegex() for url=/includeRegex/...
<li>
hudson.model.ListView.getStatusFilter() for url=/statusFilter/...
<li>
hudson.model.ListView.getDefaultColumns() for url=/defaultColumns/...
<li>
hudson.model.ListView.getItems() for url=/items/...
<li>
hudson.model.ListView.getItems() for url=/items/...
<li>
hudson.model.ListView.getColumns() for url=/columns/...
<li>
hudson.model.ListView.getColumns() for url=/columns/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getDescriptor() for url=/descriptor/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getDescriptor() for url=/descriptor/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getProperties() for url=/properties/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getActions() for url=/actions/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getOwner() for url=/owner/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getDisplayName() for url=/displayName/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getDescription() for url=/description/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getUrl() for url=/url/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getTimeline() for url=/timeline/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getBuilds() for url=/builds/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getOwnerItemGroup() for url=/ownerItemGroup/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getOwnerPrimaryView() for url=/ownerPrimaryView/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getOwnerViewActions() for url=/ownerViewActions/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getAllProperties() for url=/allProperties/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getNewPronoun() for url=/newPronoun/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getQueueItems() for url=/queueItems/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getPostConstructLandingPage() for url=/postConstructLandingPage/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getItemCreatePermission() for url=/itemCreatePermission/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getAbsoluteUrl() for url=/absoluteUrl/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getAsynchPeople() for url=/asynchPeople/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getPeople() for url=/people/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getApi() for url=/api/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getComputers() for url=/computers/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getSearchUrl() for url=/searchUrl/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getACL() for url=/aCL/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getApplicablePropertyDescriptors() for url=/applicablePropertyDescriptors/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getWidgets() for url=/widgets/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getViewName() for url=/viewName/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getApproximateQueueItemsQuickly() for url=/approximateQueueItemsQuickly/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getViewUrl() for url=/viewUrl/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getIndenter() for url=/indenter/...
<li>
hudson.model.AbstractModelObject.getSearchIndex() for url=/searchIndex/...
<li>
hudson.model.AbstractModelObject.getSearchName() for url=/searchName/...
<li>
hudson.model.AbstractModelObject.getSearch() for url=/search/...
<li>
java.lang.Object.getClass() for url=/class/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getItem(String) for url=/item/TOKEN/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getDynamic(String) for url=/dynamic/TOKEN/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getJob(String) for url=/job/TOKEN/...
<li>
hudson.model.View.getDynamic(String,StaplerRequest,StaplerResponse) for url=/TOKEN/...
</ol>
</body></html>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i managed to find a solution to my problem - question (4) above by trial and error. by changing the request url to:

```
new Ajax.Request("descriptorByName/com.mycompany.jenkins.ScriptExecutionBuilder/getParameters", {
```

Now it is working in all views, however, i still don't understand how and why, and would really appreciate answers to any of the questions i asked above